# Find all measurable sets whose subsets are measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-sets

Find all Lebesgue measurable sets $A ⊂ \mathbb{R}$ with the following property: All subsets $B ⊂ A$
are measurable.

Comment: Only sets with measure zero, because Lebesgue measure is complete.

Comment: @JonasGomes the completeness of Lebesgue measure gives you that this is true for sets of measure zero, but it doesn't prevent other sets from having the same property.

Comment: Of course @Omnomnomnom. But if the measure were not complete, not even those sets would have this property.

Answer (score 2):

If $m(A)=0$, then every subset of $A$ is measurable, since the Lebesgue measure is complete.

If $A$ is not measurable, then as it is a subset of itself, it cannot have this property.

If $m(A)>0$, imitate the construction of the Vitali Set to produce a $B\subset A$ which is not measurable.

The conclusion is: the only subsets with that property are the measure-zero sets.

Comment: If you need some more explanation in that third item, tell me.